# How to hide and show element React

Tags: reactjs

I have tried and require to be able to hide and show the test field with the click of the button in the code. I have tried other ways but i need to be able to do it with the code starting with const About...

```js
const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <hr/>
        <button>Show and hide element</button>
        {
          <div style={{ marginTop: "100px" }}>
            <form
              style={{
              margin: "auto",
              padding: "15px",
              maxWidth: "400px",
              alignContent: "center",
              }}
            >
              <label htmlFor="Test">Test</label>                 
              <input
                type="text"
                id="test"                                           
                name="test"
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        }
      </center>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    DEMO
    <About />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("rd")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="rd" />
```

Comment: `const [show_test, setShowTest] = useState(false);` and then an if-statement that checks if show_test is true. Call `setShowTest(!show_test);` when the button is clicked.

Comment: Where can i add the if statement and can you structure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just toggle it using state:

Check `useState` line and conditional rendering with `show &&`.

(working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/afoone/pL3b7enk/47/) )

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;


const About = () => {

    const [show, setShow] = useState(true)

  return (
    <div>
      <center>
        <hr/>
        <button onClick={()=>setShow(!show)}>Show and hide element</button>
        {
        show &&
          <div>
            <form
              style={{
              margin: "auto",
              padding: "15px",
              maxWidth: "400px",
              alignContent: "center",
              }}
            >
              <label htmlFor="Test">Test</label>                 
              <input
                type="text"
                id="test"                                           
                name="test"
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        }
      </center>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<About/>)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use react hook useState and set states as show/hide and update the state when you click the button and use conditional rendering to show or hide the element using state.